# Favorite Question and Answers from Second Quarter 2023

Tags: discussion, blog

### Updated

[Blog has been posted.](https://thesffblog.com/2023/07/favorite-question-and-answers-from-second-quarter-2023/)

### Original

> Like, you know, whatever!

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2023 through June 30th 2023.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2023/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2023/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2023/04/01)

**I will be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Additionally if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

Comment: It looks like the blog has an error and can't be reached at all.

Answer (score 7):

It was a weird one, but I really enjoyed that [A film where a guy has to convince the robot she’s okay](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276331/a-film-where-a-guy-has-to-convince-the-robot-she-s-okay) resulted in so many valid answers on what I thought was a fairly unique premise, counseling a dead wife in a non-humanoid robot body in a garden.

Comment: It turned out to be a bizarrely common trope

Answer (score 6):

I enjoyed answering this one;

- [Who is Mario trying to rescue in Donkey Kong?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275931/who-is-mario-trying-to-rescue-in-donkey-kong)

I've never really dug into early Nintendo lore before and it was fun reading about all the characters that never made it to the big-time.

Comment: That was a great answer.  I actually enjoyed reading the thing in it's entirety!